# Getting an error while passing array of objects to jsonapi.marshal

Tags: go, json-api

```golang
type Response struct {
    EmpID string                     `json:"EmpID" jsonapi:"primary,Employee"`
    OwnerID   string                 `json:"OwnerId" jsonapi:"attr,owner_id"`
    Start     string                 `json:"Start" jsonapi:"attr,start"`
    End       string                 `json:"End" jsonapi:"attr,end"`
    Metadata  map[string]interface{} `json:"metadata" jsonapi:"attr,Metadata"`
}

response :=[]*Response

response = **// data here //**

result := &response
```

Now, if i do , jsonapi.Marshal(result)

**error** : models should be a struct pointer or slice of struct pointers error

I tried creating a new struct and placed the array struct inside this. Something like this.

```
type ArrayResponse struct {
NewResponse *[]Response  `jsonapi:"attr,NewResponse"`
}
```

Im getting all the data inside the attributes since i have mentioned attr in the above struct. But ideally, is there a way to get the array of objects to get marshalled in jsonapi, without doing this.
I need the response in the below json api format.

```
{  
"data":[  
  {  
     "type":"filetype",
     "id":"c33e05b7-8f55-4ee1-8d61-5b5da9110b2f",
     "attributes":{  
        "created_at":"2017-07-02T09:11:10.005351Z",
        "updated_at":"2017-07-02T09:11:10.005374Z",
        "created_by":"USER_ID",
        "url_page":null,
        "resource_urls":null,
        "attachment_type_id":"1",
        "url_type_id":"1",
        "url_version":null
     },
     "relationships":{  
        "item":{  
           "data":{  
              "type":"items",
              "id":"f0c2e244-ec02-4a75-bd36-da1f703136e7"
           }
        }
     }
  },
  {  
     "type":"filetype",
     "id":"cc06bbb5-b4f8-4351-90f3-01df3f3f2116",
     "attributes":{  
        "created_at":"2017-08-02T09:11:10.005351Z",
        "updated_at":"2017-08-02T09:11:10.005374Z",
        "created_by":"USER_ID",
        "url_page":null,
        "resource_urls":null,
        "attachment_type_id":"1",
        "url_type_id":"1",
        "url_version":null
     },
     "relationships":{  
        "item":{  
           "data":{  
              "type":"items",
              "id":"b0300df2-365e-44b4-bfc4-f3170dca2289"
           }
        }
     }
  }
]}
```

Comment: You need to provide the exact code you are using.  and the exact server-response in a serialized format. I think your issue lies in passig the stings / * string / buffer formats arround and you need to treat  apples as apples.

Comment: Whatever jsonapi.Marshal is, it's pretty clear that it's particular about its argument. You're passing a pointer to a slice. Have you tried passing "a struct pointer or slice of struct pointers" as the error says?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).